# How to set the images for UITabBarItems without having titles?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I had an application in which I am adding the images for the `UITabBarItems` programatically like this..

```
    UIImage *selectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home_hvr.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"home.png"];

    UIImage *selectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_hvr.png"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"];



    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabbarcontroller.tabBar;
    self.tabbarcontroller.tabBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.tabbarcontroller.tabBar.translucent = NO;
    UITabBarItem *item0 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *item1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];

    [item0 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item0 setImage:[unselectedImage0 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];

    [item1 setSelectedImage:[selectedImage1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    [item1 setImage:[unselectedImage1 imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

since the tabbaritems doesn't have any titles it will bring a blank space at the bottom of the tab-bar pulling the image above the tab bar,I need no titles but needs to put my image inside the tab bar completely.
Can any body guide me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
UITabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
```

was done this trick worked for me .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
[[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offer_btn_active.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offer_btn.png"]];

 [[self.tabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1] setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"merchant_btn_active.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"merchant_btn.png"]];
```

Comment: setFinishedSelectedImage is deprecated in iOS 7 also it will not solve the issue